# loopback model relations auto migrate for table relations

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I created a model and set the property. after that, when i run `npm run init` it creates corresponding tables on my database.

the question is, why does this auto migration create only tables but not relations between tables ?   my expectation was with `npm run init`, it creates all database tables with my models.json with foreignKey relations

here my code.

model.json

```
...
"properties": {  
    "id": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "id"
},
"relation" : {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "user",
    "foreignKey" : "userId"
}
...
```

Comment: Those relations in Loopback are not to enforce database constraints but to help repository fetch related entities, search by related, etc. In other words, they apply on the application layer not on the database.

Comment: @marekful thanks, for the current system I am working on, they don't set database constraints but just models.json relations. do I need to make it manually on my database ? or it's okay without it

Comment: You may. It really depends on your use case / preference. Database constraints can all be checked and enforced in the application logic but sometimes it's preferable to have them.

Comment: it will automatically create the tables for you. when you insert/create an instance..